# Do any Hindu scriptures explain the science behind the astrology?

Tags: scripture, astrology

Somehow I am not challenging Astrology & I am amazed how some people are able to predict your nature & your future so accurately just by your time of birth & place of birth.

I already met some great astrologers who are amazing in their job & can tell you your past without knowing you & even predict future accurately with knowing you.

Astrologers have most accurate knowledge of cosmic events (more accurate & before than NASA)  like Lunar Eclipse & solar eclipse in next 1000 years. They know about all planets, their cycles long before even Galileo propose Heliocentric.

Is this like they are so advanced in science & knowledge of universe that we still can't imagine and they have equation to predict time as dimension to predict best possibility of future.

**What is actual science behind astrology? Do any Hindu scriptures explain this science?**

NOTE: I know astrology is not fake except for some fakers who exist even in science as scientists.

Comment: Astrology is a separate discipline, it is not Hinduism per se.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, I agree astrology is vast field & have many types. I want to relate it with Hinduism. Hinduism know about Universe, cosmic events, Heliocentric solar system much before and is most scientific & logical Astrology. The good astrologers I met are all Hindu & following the old vedic ways to learn astrology in Sanskrit (one of the world most old language ever known).

Comment: [Questions regarding Hindu astrology are allowed here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/72/are-questions-regarding-hindu-astrology-allowed-here) but [scientific speculation question are not](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/142/users-asking-for-scientific-answers-reasons/143#143)

Comment: Restricting user views relating Hinduism to valid science should not be done. It will make this community stronger with more following. How in universe it can degrade quality of posts with providing scientific & more logical facts in support of tradition, I can't understand.

Comment: You should be proud to know Hinduism is only religion that is dynamic, not stubborn, seeks scientific proof, has open ended discussion/debates among visionaries called `Shastharth` ages ago. We need this community to be more open to constructive support.

Comment: Jyotish is called  Veda's eyes but i'm not sure where.Also Jyotish=Jyoti+Ish .Now what does this sandhi actually mean?Does that mean the light through which Iswara(God) can be seen(realised) Or The Light of God (to remove darkness/ignorance and to understand the laws of nature in a better way)?

Comment: Astrology is an old science in Indian culture. The Upanishads mention it; but it is mentioned as a separate science; as a science separate from vedic knowledge. Vedic knowledge = vedanta = Hinduism. Not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, Vedic knowledge is not limited to Vedanta. 6 angas of Vedas - shiksha, chandas, vyakarana, nirukta, kalpa, jyotisha - are all integral part of Hinduism. Jyotisha is commonly known as 'astrology' today. This question is very valid for this site. I vote to reopen it.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, this question is not speculating anything. He is asking for scriptural backing for astrology, and it can be found in Brihat Parashara Jyotisha shastra. There are lot of universities and monks in India devoted to studying this science in rigor. It is as much a science as it is religion.

Comment: @ram But scientific explanation is off topic here, read here http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/143/36

Comment: @ram I have personally witnessed many astrological predictions that have become true. I have also witnessed predictions made by the physical sciences that have become true. But the knowledge is not based on Vedas. It is a separate science even as physics is a separate science. It is mentioned as being a separate science. It is not the 'science' of Brahman.

Comment: Who said Jyotisha is not based on the Vedas ? The 6 angas of Vedas are taught in every veda patashala in India. The method of pronouncing Vedas and the method of determining their meanings is only taught in the 6 angas. The science of Brahman is Vedanta, while Vedas deal with slightly more material (but still very spiritual) things. Are you saying Hinduism is confined to only Vedanta and does not include Vedas ? I don't know who came up with this definition of Hinduism